# "Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor" with "@androidx.room.Ignore`

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-jetpack

I have a Room database Entity called Conversation and I would like to `androidx.room.@Ignore` the `messages` member variable. However, when I try to run the app, I get this error.

```
/db/entity/Conversation.java:10: error: Entities and POJOs must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type).
public final class Conversation {
             ^
  Tried the following constructors but they failed to match:
  Conversation(int,java.util.List<com.example.app.db.entity.Message>) -> [param:id -> matched field:id, param:messages -> matched field:unmatched]/db/entity/Conversation.java:12: error: Cannot find setter for field.
    private final int id = 0;
```

Here is the entity code.

```
/**
 * Entity used to model the conversation SQLite table in the database.
 */
@Entity(tableName = "conversation")
data class Conversation(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Int,
    @Ignore val messages: List<Message>
)
```

When I comment out the `@Ignore val messages...` line, the app compiles.

I've tried both Room database versions `2.2.5` and `2.3.0-alpha03` and both exhibit the same errors.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by converting the entity to a non-data class:

```
/**
 * Entity used to model the conversation SQLite table in the database.
 */
@Entity(tableName = "conversation")
class Conversation constructor(@PrimaryKey val id: Int) {

    @Ignore
    val messages = mutableListOf<Message>()
}
```